# Django - add-up Sum of multiple model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, sum, aggregate

How can i add-up the Sum of each Model here? In the end i simply want to have one single value for all up_votes /down_votes accross all 3 models. See example below:

```
def calc_user_feedback():
    users = User.objects.all()
    try:
        for user in users:
            fed_qry_up_votes = Model1.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('up_vote')) + \
                               Model2.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('up_vote')) + \
                               Model3.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('up_vote'))
            fed_qry_down_votes = Model1.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('down_vote')) + \
                               Model2.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('down_vote')) + \
                               Model3.objects.filter(author=user).aggregate(Sum('down_vote'))

            logger.info("Overall user feedback calculated successfully.")
    except:
        logger.info("Error processing task: 'Calculate user feedback', please investigate")
```

Comment: Why exactly did you make *three* models? If two things are that similar, it is often useful to use the same model.

Comment: I absolutly with you, but my application has several very complex implementation and i was sadly not able to stay confirm. Im not able to change everything afterward  as the code has started like that years ago ...

Comment: What's the `related_name` for `author` on each model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `author` has no `related_name` set on each model:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

users = (
    User.objects.annotate(up_votes_1=Sum("model1_set__up_vote"))
    .annotate(up_votes_2=Sum("model2_set__up_vote"))
    .annotate(up_votes_3=Sum("model3_set__up_vote"))
    .annotate(total=F("up_votes_1") + F("up_votes_2") + F("up_votes_3"))
)
```

Now you can iterate over users and get a total for each one.

Comment: But it also seems that i only get back the number of objects not the number of the actual up_vote/down_vote field if i use count

Comment: You don't need to use count, just use the `total` field.